# How to find lines that contain more than a single whitespace between strings in unix?

Tags: unix, grep

I have lines like

```
1|Harry|says|hi
2|Ron|says|bye
3|Her   mi oh ne|is|silent
4|The|above|sentence|is|weird
```

I need a grep command that'll detect the third line.

This is what Im doing.

```
grep -E '" "" "+' $dname".txt" >> $dname"_error.txt"
```

The logic on which I'm basing this is, the first white space must be followed by one or more white spaces to be detected as an error.

$dname is a variable that holds the filename path.

How do I get my desired output?

( which is

```
      3|Her   mi oh ne|is|silent
```

)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just this will do:

```
grep "  " ${dname}.txt >> ${dname}_error.txt
```

The two spaces in a quoted string work fine. The `-E` turns the pattern into an extended regular expression, which makes this needlessly complicated here.

Comment: The `-E` turns the pattern into an extended regular expression, grep patterns are always regexes, unless the `-F` option is given.

Comment: Wouldn't this only catch lines containing two spaces? If so I don't see how it answers the question.

Comment: @Prometheus any line that has more than two consecutive spaces will, by definition, have two consecutive spaces, so this command will find them as well.

Comment: Okay, I see. Maybe I was mistaking it for a fixed string.

Answer (score 7):

```
grep '[[:space:]]\{2,\}' ${dname}.txt >> ${dname}_error.txt
```

If you want to catch 2 or more whitespaces.

Answer (score 2):

If you want *2 or more* spaces, then:

```
grep -E "\s{2,}" ${dname}.txt >> ${dname}_error.txt
```

The reason why your pattern doesn't work is because of the quotation marks inside. `\s` is used for [space]. You could actually do the same thing with:

```
grep -E '  +' ${dname}.txt >> ${dname}_error.txt
```

But it's difficult to tell exactly what you are looking for with that version. `\s\s+` would also work, but `\s{2,}` is the most concise and also gives you the option of setting an upper limit. If you wanted to find 2, 3, or 4 spaces in a row, you would use `\s{2,4}`

Comment: They both have been tested and work on grep (GNU grep) 2.9. Which version are you using?

Comment: Methinks you may need to reexamine your definition of "concise" :-)

Answer (score 2):

below are the four ways.

```
pearl.268> sed -n 's/  /&/p' ${dname}.txt >> ${dname}_error.txt
pearl.269> awk '$0~/  /{print $0}' ${dname}.txt >> ${dname}_error.txt
pearl.270> grep '  ' ${dname}.txt >> ${dname}_error.txt
pearl.271> perl -ne '/  / && print' ${dname}.txt >> ${dname}_error.txt
```