# Grep not recognizing white space

Tags: regex, command-line, grep, whitespace

I have a file (the first chapter of Harry Potter) with large amounts of white space. For example:

```
 CHAPTER ONE
  The Boy Who Lived
   M r and Mrs Dursley, of number four, Privet Drive, were
   proud to say that they were perfectly normal, thank
   you very much. They were the last people you’d expect to be
   involved in anything strange or mysterious, because they just
   didn’t hold with such nonsense.
    Mr Dursley was the director of a fi rm called Grunnings,
    which made drills. He was a big, beefy man with hardly
    any neck, although he did have a very large moustache.
    Mrs Dursley was thin and blonde and had nearly twice the
    usual amount of neck, which came in very useful as she spent
    so much of her time craning over garden fences, spying on the
    neighbours. The Dursleys had a small son called Dudders and
```

My objective, while learning command line tools, is to (first identify with `grep` and then) remove all white space, as follows:

```
 CHAPTER ONE
The Boy Who Lived
M r and Mrs Dursley, of number four, Privet Drive, were
proud to say that they were perfectly normal, thank
you very much. They were the last people you’d expect to be
involved in anything strange or mysterious, because they just
didn’t hold with such nonsense.
Mr Dursley was the director of a fi rm called Grunnings,
which made drills. He was a big, beefy man with hardly
any neck, although he did have a very large moustache.
Mrs Dursley was thin and blonde and had nearly twice the
usual amount of neck, which came in very useful as she spent
so much of her time craning over garden fences, spying on the
neighbours. The Dursleys had a small son called Dudders and
```

I'm trying to identify the lines with multiple white spaces using `grep`. In this, I've attempted the following (amongst others):

```
$ grep "(\s){2,}" file
$ grep "(\ ){2,}" file
$ grep "([[:space:]]){2,}" file
$ grep "[[:space:]]{2,}" file
```

None of these has produced any matches. I've confirmed that there is white space in there with Vim. I've similarly confirmed each of those syntaxes on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com). I've also checked the file against `grep " " file` (and varieties) and seen all lines with *any* white space output correctly.

What is the correct syntax for this query?

Comment: Can you also include snippets of example content from the file to verify the whitespace?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find lines that contain more than a single whitespace between strings in unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736295/how-to-find-lines-that-contain-more-than-a-single-whitespace-between-strings-in)

Comment: @dsillman2000 Added. The further in the file you go the more white space there is.

Comment: Have you tried using egrep or some other variant of grep? The default invocation doesn't support full perl-like regular expressions.

Comment: "{2,} matches the previous token between 2 and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)" - Is this what you want? Or you want 
'grep "(\s)[2,]" file' ?

Comment: `grep -E "[[:space:]]{2,}" file` is the right way of using a POSIX ERE pattern with `grep`. The patterns are fine, you just did not use the right option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
cat file
 CHAPTER ONE
  The Boy Who Lived
   M r and Mrs Dursley, of number four, Privet Drive, were
   proud to say that they were perfectly normal, thank
   you very much. They were the last people you’d expect to be
   involved in anything strange or mysterious, because they just
   didn’t hold with such nonsense.
    Mr Dursley was the director of a fi rm called Grunnings,
    which made drills. He was a big, beefy man with hardly
    any neck, although he did have a very large moustache.
    Mrs Dursley was thin and blonde and had nearly twice the
    usual amount of neck, which came in very useful as she spent
    so much of her time craning over garden fences, spying on the
    neighbours. The Dursleys had a small son called Dudders and
```

Your best bet is `sed` to delete leading spaces:

```
sed -E 's/^[[:blank:]]{2,}//' file
 CHAPTER ONE
The Boy Who Lived
M r and Mrs Dursley, of number four, Privet Drive, were
proud to say that they were perfectly normal, thank
you very much. They were the last people you’d expect to be
involved in anything strange or mysterious, because they just
didn’t hold with such nonsense.
Mr Dursley was the director of a fi rm called Grunnings,
which made drills. He was a big, beefy man with hardly
any neck, although he did have a very large moustache.
Mrs Dursley was thin and blonde and had nearly twice the
usual amount of neck, which came in very useful as she spent
so much of her time craning over garden fences, spying on the
neighbours. The Dursleys had a small son called Dudders and
```

Or with `awk`:

```
awk '{sub(/^[[:blank:]]{2,}/,"")} 1' file
# same output
```

If you only want to *identify* those lines that have 2 or more spaces at the beginning with `grep`:

```
grep -E '^[[:blank:]]{2,}' file
```

The issue YOU were having is that `grep` and `sed` use Basic Regular Expressions (BRE) as a default. You need to use the `-E` option to trigger using Extended Regular Expressions (ERE).

[HERE](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Basic-vs-Extended.html) is the difference BRE and ERE.

`awk` uses ERE as a default.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I figured it was going to be a `sed` to remove (although I wanted to try to use `awk`, as well--my objective with this is to learn some basic command line tool functionality). I was trying to figure out specifically the `grep ` functionality for the search part of the problem.

Comment: Same regex works with `grep`. You just need to add `-E` for *extended regular expression* or use `egrep`